# Using the Ubuntu installer partition manager?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm about to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC. I have created an extended partition and inside that created a 24GB logical ext4 partiton for Ubuntu and a 2GB logical swap area. I've gone into the "something else" option and need to know a few things before I continue. First, what does the "Format?" option do and should I use it? Second, does it matter if the swap area is listed before or after the ext4 partition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting is restoring the hard drive, basically. It removes everything.

And no, the partition listing doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cxdy . I realize that formatting removes all data on a drive, but what I'm talking about here is the tick box option. Please refer to this image: http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c340/wyattowen1/Screenshotfrom2014-04-24005645_zps3f1903c0.png

Comment: If you check that, during installation, Ubuntu will format that drive.

Comment: By drive, do you mean partition? I'm asking that because the option is available for each partition, not just the main drive. @cxdy

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, I typically forget that people primarily partition their hard drives instead of having separate hard drives aha.

Comment: Ok, so all the format option does is remove any and all data from that partition? And since I just created the partition, there is no need to use the format option, correct? @cxdy

Comment: Exactly. I would format it anyway, just in case. But yeah, that's all it does. Sorry for the late reply by the way. I never got a notification.

Comment: Heh, well I already did it anyway. All went well, just having some issues with Win 7 not showing up at boot. @cxdy

Comment: Alright. Um, let me think of how to fix that, then i'll get back to you!

Comment: Alright! If I helped solve your question, mark me as best answer please! Unless you need anything else?

Comment: Marked as best answer. Only thing I can think of ATM is that after reinstalling Ubuntu Software Center it is now displaying as "Ubuntu Software Centre" I guess it thinks I'm in a different location. @cxdy

Comment: Nah, you may have your language set to English (UK), or maybe it just was renamed to that in the update. I don't think it's a problem though.

Comment: My language is English (US) it's not really a _problem_ just an annoyance. I don't like it displaying as a European name or whatever it is. @cxdy

Comment: I looked it up, and I'm seeing that `Ubuntu Software Centre` is the official name of the application, and cannot be changed.

Comment: Hmm, well it was called "Ubuntu Software Center" upon installation and on the LiveUSB stick. @cxdy

Comment: Yeah, but in the update, the name changed, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it was an "_update_" but rather just a reinstall. I looked at the Software Center on Wikipedia and it stated that "The application is called the "Ubuntu Software Centre" outside of the USA." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center @cxdy

Comment: Hmm. No clue, sorry!

Comment: No problem! @Master_W